# How to use openGL and GPU to draw a QImage in QQuickPaintedItem (raspberry pi)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application on Raspberry Pi 4 and I use a QQuickPaintedItem to create a class and use it in qml. I use QPainter to draw a QImage right now. I wanted to know is there any way to turn this QImage to an openGL texture and draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an FBO: [QOpenGLFrameBufferObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglframebufferobject.html) in Qt.

If you want to draw an item instead, you can use a [QQuickFramebufferObject](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qquickframebufferobject.html).